# I want to pass json object as a raw data using @Body in retrofit, but I am unable to add an image file inside the Request Object, how can I achieve it

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, multipart

Data in JSON format I need to pass is:

```json
{
   "user":{
      "email":"xxxx",
      "password":"xxxx",
      "first_name":"XXXX",
      "last_name":"XXXX",
      "date_of_birth":"XXXX",
      "image":"myFile.jpg",
      "location":"XXXX",
      "my_list1":[
         {
            "first_name":"XXXX",
            "last_name":"XXXX",
            "telephone_number":"XXXX"
         },
         {
            "first_name":"XXXX",
            "last_name":"XXXX",
            "telephone_number":"XXXX"
         }
      ],
      "my_list2":[
         {
            "id":"1"
         },
         {
            "id":"2"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I can not add an image in mainRequestObj while using:

```
@POST("users")
Call<MainResponse> register(@Header("abc") String abc,@Body MainRequestObj mainRequestObj);
```

Is there any way I can pass the image as a file in the raw body format? I am using retrofit 2.9.0. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, your JSON contains the NAME of a file. If you want to send the FILE CONTENT, then well: you have to write code for that. You need to READ the file, take its bytes, encode them somehow, and add that to your JSON structure, and then do the reverse on the other end.

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat. If use this approach, then the backend team will also have to modify the code and add the decoding logic there right? So, if I don't find any other solution then I think I have no other option than this. Also, should I convert the file into Base64 to send as a string/byte[] ?

Comment: Sounds correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your bitmap into a base64 string and send it to the server.

But you should send the multipart request. As I read your comment there is a list of objects that you want to send to the server. You should create a POJO that contains your list of data and then send it along with the multipart request.

Here is some code example:

```
class SyncUpData {
@SerializedName("Products")
var products: List<ProductDTO>? = null

@SerializedName("ProductTax")
var productTax: List<ProductTaxDTO>? = null
}
```

And along with your multipart request do like this:

```
    val str = GsonBuilder().create().toJson(syncUpObj)
    val jsonObject: JSONObject = JSONObject(str)
    val body = jsonObject.toString(1)
    
    val syncUp = RequestBody.create("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull(), body)
```

Your API Call:

```
@Multipart
@POST("")
Call<ResponseDTO> syncUpNow(@Part MultipartBody.Part[] images,
                                        @Part("syncUp") RequestBody myObj
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use form data for your `POST` API then you can achieve this. you have to get some help from your back-end developer as well. check this below example code. Try this way and let me know your finding

```
@Multipart
@POST("expenses/upload")
Observable<UploadExpensesWithImageResponse> uploadExpensesWithImageAPI(
        @Header("Authorization") String accessToken,
        @Part  MultipartBody.Part[] picture,
        @Part("store_id") RequestBody store_id,
        @Part("amount") RequestBody amount,
        @Part("expense_date") RequestBody expense_date);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Dulanga, Thanks for answering. I was about to use this approach but when we declare the parts of the form-data in our interface method e.g. uploadExpensesWithImageAPI(), we need to specify all the parameters there, but I have to pass list data as parameters then how can I pass them using form data when I don't know how many items are there in the list? That's why I chose to send as a raw data object but then it doesn't support the image file. Please let me know if you have any solution for that.

Comment: Hi @JB08
You can try as in this link 1st answer with PartMap 
https://coderedirect.com/questions/390412/upload-file-using-both-multipart-and-json-key-value-pairs-with-retrofit2

Comment: I tried the solution with PartMap as suggested by you and I could achieve the intended result with it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JBO8 Great, give an upvote for my answer :)

Comment: @JB08 Hey that link is expired can you re-share that link with me?